# How do I create an empty pickle file with a given name?

Tags: python, pickle

I want to do the following:

1- Check if a pkl file with a given name exists
2- If not, create a new file with that given name
3- Load the data into that file

```
if not os.path.isfile(filename):
    with open(filename,"wb") as file:
        pickle.dump(result, file)
else:
    pickle.dump(result, open(filename,"wb") )
```

However, this rises an error even though I have checked the file exists (shouldnt even enter the if!!) with the given path:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
with open(filename_i,"wb") as file:
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '.'
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is `file(filename, "wb")` on your second line?

Comment: what error? Post the error logs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
import os
import pickle

if not os.path.isfile("test_pkl.pkl"):
    with open("test_pkl.pkl",'wb') as file:
        pickle.dump("some obejct", file)
```

So first it checks if file exists, if not create the file ("wb") and then dump some object to it via pickle pickle.dump

Comment: Thanks! I am getting the following error:   File "AE_PCA.py", line 203, in main
    with open(filename,'wb') as file:
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/'
 @Klemen Koleša

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is more clear:

## Imports

```
import os
import pickle
```

## Create pickle and save data

```
dict = { 'Test1': 1, 'Test2': 2, 'Test3': 3 }
filename = "test_pkl.pkl"


if not os.path.isfile(filename):
   with open(filename,'wb') as file:
       pickle.dump(dict, file)
   file.close()
```

## Opening the pickle file

```
  infile = open(filename,'rb')
  new_dict = pickle.load(infile)
  infile.close()
```

## Test the data

```
  print(new_dict)
  print(new_dict == dict)
  print(type(new_dict))
```

## Output

```
  {'Test1': 1, 'Test2': 2, 'Test3': 3}
  True
  <class 'dict'>
```

Comment: btw, don't use `dict` as the name of a variable.

Comment: @Bjoerk thanks but I get the same error I told Klemen